# Domain button greyed out/unclickable in shopify

Tags: shopify

I am trying to add a domain to my Shopify site. I am relatively new to Shopify and I noticed the simplest things are made very difficult with this platform. I want to add a domain to my Shopify shop. The problem is that the domains button is greyed out and unclickable. I am using the Boundless theme, is the theme the issue? Or am I missing a step? How can I add a domain to my Shopify site if the domains button is not clickable?

Comment: Best to ask in the help section for Shopify site. https://help.shopify.com/questions

Comment: Or debug your computer. The unclickable Domains link is only unclickable due to your computer+browser combo. You do not mention that. Perhaps you should!

Comment: Nah I Tried on all 3 of my computers with all the browsers i have- Chrome, Firefox, and IE it's the same. It has nothing to do with my computers or browser. There must be a step I'm missing somewhere

Answer (score 0):

It's greyed out because you are not on a paid Shopify plan yet and that is a feature only available on paid plans. If this is a development store then the developer account needs to turn it over to you before you can upgrade to a paid plan.